# Ajax post returns nothing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to send some data with post to a php file but for some reason its not being posted. I receive an empty array in console log from the php file on `var_dump`.
Here is code I have in these files:

> index.php

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="resetPassword">Reset Password</button>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function (e){
   $("#resetPassword").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: "scripts/process.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {name: 'test'},
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data) {
          if (data === 'Success') {
            new PNotify({
              title: 'Success!!!',
              text: 'Request completed successfully.',
              type: 'success',
              styling: 'bootstrap3'
            });
            $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
            $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable().ajax.reload();
          } else {
            console.log(data);
            new PNotify({
              title: 'Error!!!',
              text: data,
              type: 'error',
              styling: 'bootstrap3'
            });
            //document.getElementById("status").className += " alert-danger";
            //$("#status").html(data);
          }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText+" - "+thrownError);
        } 
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

> Here is the php file process.php.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

> Result in console.log:

```
array(0) {}
```

> Solution:

**Remove `processData: false`**

thanks guys.

Comment: Why do you even expect `data` to be `Success`? It cannot work as you did. `data` is the content of you php's `var_dump($_POST);`, and not `Success`.

Comment: And remove the `processData: false`, then your parameters should work too.

Comment: Kindly check your data returns success, because you are trying to check with the `===` Since it will check more exact results and check the `console.log(data)`. In your php file check the return values. do exit after you are required condition,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove processData:false, section and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
before or after

```
e.preventDefault();

var formData = $("#yourform_id").serializeArray(); //form data
```

and replace data with this line datas

```
data: formData,
```

remove

```
processData:false,
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are using while returning data in process.php file? ECHO or RETURN?

Try ECHO, if it does not work then try RETURN statement. Rest of your code seems OK.

To debug use print_r() on scripts/process.php and check it in browser's console for out put. Also, you can use toSource of javascript to check variable's data

Answer (score 0):

If you try by  `processData:false` ,its need data is raw string

change from

```
   data: {name: 'test'},
```

into

```
   data: "name=test",
```